# How long with no traffic before an Openshift gear goes idle?

Tags: openshift

In the non-scalable singular gear how long without traffic before the gear goes idle. I've looked in https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/index.html and it doesn't seem to be in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the correct answer is 24 hours.

Comment: In the FAQ on that page it still indicates that idling is done for free tier accounts.

Answer (score 3):

Gear idling is now formally documented in the OpenShift Online pricing page:

https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing

In the Free plan, idling occurs when an application has had no traffic (or git pushes) for 24 hours.  In the Bronze and Silver plans, applications are not idled.